# SharePoint 2013: No Code Solution for Modal Dialog on All Task Lists in Site

Tags: 2013, list, form

SharePoint 2013 - I'm looking for a no code solution which I could apply to a top level site which would allow the List Form Modal Dialog popups to be turned on by default for all Task list in any subsite currently available or created in the future.

I am aware of how to turn on the Modal Dialogs per list, and was hoping to achieve a default behavior of being enabled to avoid having to explain it to our site administrators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "no code" resolution to that. You can create some declarative list instance that you deploy as a feature or use PowerShell to set it after the fact, but both of those are "code" solutions of one form or another.

Here is an example from: http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/change-sharepoint-list-settings-using.html

```
#Change these variables to your site URL and list name
$site = Get-SPSite http://portal
$listName = "Shared Documents"

#Walk through each site in the site collection
$site | Get-SPWeb | ForEach-Object {

#Get the list in this site
$list = $_.Lists[$listName]

#Make the list changes

#Update the list
$list.Update()
}

#Dispose of the site object
$site.Dispose()
```

With this code above you would insert the call to your property

`$list.NavigateForFormsPages = $true;`

You can add more to this script so ti actually grabs a web application and loops thru all sites and all lists and set's that property.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesus Shelby mention, there is no code solution for the task that you are trying to achieve. Another useful link that can help you:

http://alinimer.wordpress.com/2013/02/25/open-pages-and-forms-in-modal-dialog-for-sharepoint-2013/